# SQL Server Row totals in pivot query

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot, rows

I am trying to make a row in the end of the result set that shows the totals.

My query is this:

```
SELECT 
[ ] = ISNULL(CAST(GEN_idPaciente AS VARCHAR)+'-'+nombrePaciente, 'TOTAL'),
[2016-11-01] = MAX([2016-11-01]),
[2016-11-02] = MAX([2016-11-02]),
[2016-11-03] = MAX([2016-11-03]),
[2016-11-04] = MAX([2016-11-04]),
TOTAL = COUNT([2016-11-01]) + COUNT([2016-11-02]) + COUNT([2016-11-03]) + COUNT([2016-11-04])
FROM 
(
    SELECT GEN_Paciente.GEN_idPaciente,COALESCE(GEN_ape_paternoPaciente, '')+' '+COALESCE(GEN_ape_maternoPaciente, '')+' '+COALESCE(GEN_nombrePaciente, '') AS nombrePaciente,HOS_fechaCategorizacion,HOS_nivel_riesgoCategorizacion+CAST(HOS_nivel_dependenciaCategorizacion AS VARCHAR) as riesgoDependencia
    FROM HOS_Categorizacion
    INNER JOIN HOS_Hospitalizacion
    ON HOS_Hospitalizacion.HOS_idHospitalizacion = HOS_Categorizacion.HOS_idHospitalizacion
    INNER JOIN GEN_Paciente
    ON GEN_Paciente.GEN_idPaciente = HOS_Hospitalizacion.GEN_idPaciente
    WHERE HOS_nivel_riesgoCategorizacion IS NOT NULL
) src
PIVOT
(
  MAX(riesgoDependencia)
  for HOS_fechaCategorizacion in ([2016-11-01],[2016-11-02],[2016-11-03],[2016-11-04])
) p
GROUP BY
ROLLUP(CAST(GEN_idPaciente AS VARCHAR)+'-'+nombrePaciente)
```

This gives me this result:

[image]

But as you can see the totals for the rows are right but the totals for the columns are wrong because I am using MAX instead of COUNT, but I only need COUNT in the TOTAL row, the others have to be MAX, so I wrote this query:

```
SELECT 
[ ] = ISNULL(CAST(GEN_idPaciente AS VARCHAR)+'-'+nombrePaciente, 'TOTAL'),
[2016-11-01] = CASE WHEN CAST(GEN_idPaciente AS VARCHAR)+'-'+nombrePaciente IS NOT NULL THEN MAX([2016-11-01]) ELSE COUNT([2016-11-01]) END,
[2016-11-02] = CASE WHEN CAST(GEN_idPaciente AS VARCHAR)+'-'+nombrePaciente IS NOT NULL THEN MAX([2016-11-02]) ELSE COUNT([2016-11-02]) END,
[2016-11-03] = CASE WHEN CAST(GEN_idPaciente AS VARCHAR)+'-'+nombrePaciente IS NOT NULL THEN MAX([2016-11-03]) ELSE COUNT([2016-11-03]) END,
[2016-11-04] = CASE WHEN CAST(GEN_idPaciente AS VARCHAR)+'-'+nombrePaciente IS NOT NULL THEN MAX([2016-11-04]) ELSE COUNT([2016-11-04]) END,
TOTAL = COUNT([2016-11-01]) + COUNT([2016-11-02]) + COUNT([2016-11-03]) + COUNT([2016-11-04])
FROM 
(
    SELECT GEN_Paciente.GEN_idPaciente,COALESCE(GEN_ape_paternoPaciente, '')+' '+COALESCE(GEN_ape_maternoPaciente, '')+' '+COALESCE(GEN_nombrePaciente, '') AS nombrePaciente,HOS_fechaCategorizacion,HOS_nivel_riesgoCategorizacion+CAST(HOS_nivel_dependenciaCategorizacion AS VARCHAR) as riesgoDependencia
    FROM HOS_Categorizacion
    INNER JOIN HOS_Hospitalizacion
    ON HOS_Hospitalizacion.HOS_idHospitalizacion = HOS_Categorizacion.HOS_idHospitalizacion
    INNER JOIN GEN_Paciente
    ON GEN_Paciente.GEN_idPaciente = HOS_Hospitalizacion.GEN_idPaciente
    WHERE HOS_nivel_riesgoCategorizacion IS NOT NULL
) src
PIVOT
(
  MAX(riesgoDependencia)
  for HOS_fechaCategorizacion in ([2016-11-01],[2016-11-02],[2016-11-03],[2016-11-04])
) p
GROUP BY
ROLLUP(CAST(GEN_idPaciente AS VARCHAR)+'-'+nombrePaciente)
```

But that is not working

[image]

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you want to count all columns which are not null. In this case you should just look at the condition `IS NULL` and not at the actual value at all. Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, val1 VARCHAR(100),val2 VARCHAR(100),val3 VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('row1_val1','row1_val2',NULL)
,('row2_val1','row2_val2','row2_val3')
,(NULL,'row2_val2',NULL)
,(NULL,NULL,'row2_val3')
,(NULL,NULL,NULL);

SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN val1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
      +CASE WHEN val2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
      +CASE WHEN val3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS CountOfValNotNull
FROM @tbl
```

### UPDATE: Add a final *Totals* Row

You'd need ugly fiddling with a CTE, an additional sort column, `UNION ALL` to add another row and a sub_select.

Use the outer-most `ORDER BY` to get the artificial Totals-Row to the end

**hint:** Use the @tbl variable from above!

```
WITH SortedRows AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS SortColumn
          ,*
          ,CASE WHEN val1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
          +CASE WHEN val2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
          +CASE WHEN val3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS CountOfValNotNull
    FROM @tbl
)

SELECT tbl1.*
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM SortedRows
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 999999,0,'','','',(SELECT SUM(CountOfValNotNull) FROM SortedRows)
) AS tbl1
ORDER BY tbl1.SortColumn
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but in your example the totals are in the final column and i already have that, what i need is the total in the final row (showing the total per column)

Comment: @user953851, you want a final sum of all these values? Where should this value appear? In a last *total sum row*? This is something your presentation layer or reporting engine should calculate... If you really need this from SQL Server you can do this, but it's ugly... See my update

Comment: Ok, thanks, i think i will have to do it in the presentation layer.

Comment: @user953851 It is very kind of you to say *thanks*, but it would be even kinder, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!